# SQLAlchemy 2.0 SQLBind Parameter NVARCHAR Invalid Precision value (0) Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

In a python method, I have a database table being reflected into a table object. The table that causes the error has some `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns, `NVARCHAR(255)` and a `biginteger` column, no other numeric columns. I use the columns from that table to populate a new temporary table. When I updated to SQLAlchemy 2.0, I receive the pyodbc error `Invalid Precision Value (0) (SQLBindParameter)`.

The error occurs in the `conn.execute(tmp.insert(), tbl_data)` method. I truncated the code for brevity. Is this a bug in SQLAlchemy 2.0 or is there a bug in my code?

These are the methods that do the reflection and create the temporary table:

```py
    def sql_merge(self, data: dict, j: int = 0) -> bool:
        with self.engine.begin() as conn:
            tbl: Table = Table(k, self.meta, autoload_with=self.engine)
            tbl_data = self.sql_arrange(v, tbl.c.keys())
            if self.dialect == 'mssql':
                tmp = self.temp_table(tbl.c)
                tmp.create(conn)
                conn.execute(tmp.insert(), tbl_data)
                merge_qry = merge_str(self.db, self.schema, k,
                                      tmp.c.keys(), **merge_dict)  # type: ignore
                conn.execute(text(merge_qry))
                tmp.drop(conn)
                self.tmp_meta.remove(tmp)

    def temp_table(self, cols: sa.sql.expression.ColumnCollection) -> Table:
        """Create temporary table based on dialect"""
        new_cols = [Column(col.name, col.type) for col in cols]
        if self.dialect == 'mssql':
            tbl_name = "#tmp"
            return Table(tbl_name, self.tmp_meta, *new_cols)
```

**Note** This is fully working in SQLAlchemy 1.4 and I've checked the 2.0 docs but can't find anything related to this issue